# SOLVED Problem Broadcom 43142 wifi

Tags: release-loki, wifi, drivers, networking

I'm on Elementary OS 0.4 and i've a problem with the wifi connection, i tryied to fix it with all i've found on the web, but it still doesn't work. With  " lshw -C network " i got that:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7800000-f7807fff
```

Could anyone help me? I'm a noob.

Comment: Surfing on the web i read about a blacklist so i use this command to verify and i get this: 'grep -R brcm /etc/modprobe.d
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist brcm80211
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist brcmfmac
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist brcmsmac'

Comment: @lemonslice with the command iwconfig i get: enp2s0    no wireless extensions. (that is the Ethernet interface)

lo        no wireless extensions. (i don't know what is this)

Comment: Instead of writing "SOLVED" in your questions title please accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark ✓

Comment: How did you fix it? I now have the same problem. How did you disable secure mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED the problem was that secure boot was enabled, now wireless connection is shown in the option and works!

Comment: Hi Andrea, this answer might be more helpful to other searchers if you added the steps you took to rectify your issue

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the Broadcom drivers, open terminal and paste

> **sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source**

Reboot your machine and try to connect to the wifi.

Comment: Thank you Giovanni, this is what i got now: bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8).

Comment: Is the wifi working now?

Comment: Yes, now it works, but the problem was the secure boot enabled!

Answer (score 1):

You might have to execute iwconfig manually (the card is there but it is down):

```
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up
service network-manager restart
```

(Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Hp laptop the solution was disable secure boot and enable legacy 
tutorial here https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04784866